# Null pointer dynamic Image Button creation in a different Activity

Tags: android, dynamic, nullpointerexception, imagebutton

I'm trying to Make an Image Button OnClick create another dynamic ImageButton in real time to a Layout on a seperate activity, but the layout where the new button creates keeps turning up null with a nullpointerexception error and the app crashes, what am I doing wrong?

```
 package org.iimed.www;


import android.R.drawable;
import android.R.string;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.text.Layout;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;


import android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import org.iimed.www.Sundayopen;

    public class Penicillins extends Activity implements OnClickListener {






            public void onCreate(Bundle SavedInstanceState){
                 super.onCreate(SavedInstanceState);  
                 setContentView(R.layout.penicillin);
                ImageButton addmed = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.addmed);
                 addmed.setOnClickListener(this);






            }









                     public void onClick(View v){
                         switch (v.getId()) {

                         case R.id.addmed:
                             startActivity(new Intent(Penicillins.this,Sundayopen.class));
                        LayoutParams param = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                         final RelativeLayout ll = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.sundayopen);
                         final  ImageButton  ab = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.adaba);

                ab.setLayoutParams(param);
                ll.addView(ab);


            }}}
```

The Activity I want it to appear in

```
package org.iimed.www;

import org.iimed.www.MainActivity;
import org.iimed.www.Iimedja;

import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View;

import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
public class Sundayopen extends Activity implements OnClickListener {   

    ImageButton ab;
       @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle iimed) {
         super.onCreate(iimed);
         setContentView(R.layout.sundayopen);
         ImageButton ab = new ImageButton(getApplicationContext());
         ImageButton hb1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.homebutton1);

         ImageButton sbc = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.satlidopen);
         ImageButton abb = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.abbutton);
         sbc.setOnClickListener(this);
         hb1.setOnClickListener(this);
         abb.setOnClickListener(this);
         ab.setOnClickListener(this);
    }


         public void onClick(View v){
             switch (v.getId()) {
             case R.id.homebutton1:
                startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
                 break;
             case R.id.satlidopen:
                 MediaPlayer media = MediaPlayer.create(Sundayopen.this, R.raw.openlid);
                 media.start();
                startActivity(new Intent(this,Iimedja.class));
                break;
             case R.id.abbutton:

                    startActivity(new Intent(this, ImageTextListViewActivity.class));

             }
         }




        }
```

Thanks for your patience I'm very new
I've edited the main class up top to what I'm trying with now, I just created an XML ImageButton and assigned an ID to be called, rather then making it on the fly and setting it's parameters. Still no luck though :/

```
Stack
        Thread [<1> main] (Suspended (exception NullPointerException))  
    <VM does not provide monitor information>   
    Penicillins.onClick(View) line: 63  
    ImageButton(View).performClick() line: 4354 
    View$PerformClick.run() line: 17961 
    Handler.handleCallback(Message) line: 725   
    ViewRootImpl$ViewRootHandler(Handler).dispatchMessage(Message) line: 92 
    Looper.loop() line: 137 
    ActivityThread.main(String[]) line: 5328    
    Method.invokeNative(Object, Object[], Class, Class[], Class, int, boolean) line: not available [native method]  
    Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 511  
    ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() line: 1102 
    ZygoteInit.main(String[]) line: 869 
    NativeStart.main(String[]) line: not available [native method]
```

Comment: here you are not initializing the `imagebutton`. try initialize it and then check :)

Comment: Do I initialize the imageButton ab in this activity or in the activity I want it to appear?

Comment: initialize it in the activity you want to appear in

Comment: I edited my question, this is what I'm using now and I'm still getting the null error on `ll.addView(ab);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as i can see, you are using improper variable declaration in your code.
You have declared same **ImageButton ab** at the global level and at the local level too.

Once you remove the global variable declaration, you will see an error like this:

> change the modifier of Image button ab to final.

Similar case goes with the **RelativeLayout ll** too.

Also, it is better to use LinearLayout in case of dynamic view creation, as you will have more control of their positioning.

Comment: How to I change the modifier of ab to final? this is the only place it is ? EDIT I changed the OnClicker to public final

Comment: can you please print your whole stacktrace here??
The stack trace points exact exceptions which is really easy to undertsand...it may help me

Comment: I am using a new code so I have a seperate xml for the ImageButton I can call an id on, still having no luck, check my question edit for new cod and stack, thanks for your patience.

Comment: sorry for late reply...as i was a little busy..i will look into your code and reply you very soon..thanks

Comment: No worries, I got it working dynamically without the I.D, but now I'm stuck on how to save the button persistently. I've been trying with shared preferences but no love.

Answer (score 0):

You are not creating object of image button.
It should be like

```
ImageButton ab = new ImageButton(getApplicationContext);
```

Answer (score 0):

Initialize ab like this.

```
ImageButton ab = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ab);
```

Answer (score 0):

First initialize take your layout id which reqire

```
ImageButton ab = (ImageButton)findviewbyid(R.id.btnAb);
```

OR If you take dynamic ImageButton

```
ImageButton ab = new ImageButton(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

The nullpointer error is because of in your `onClick` Listener you have not even initialized the `ImageButton ab;` and you are directly using it. So First initialize it and then set drawable.

```
    addmed.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
         int i;
         RelativeLayout il = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.sundayopen); 
         ImageButton ab= (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.<buttonID>); 
         public void onClick(View v){
             ab.setId(i);
            ab.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.adaba);

            il.addView(ab);
         }});
```